# Align title and image in the same line, woocommerce product category page

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, line

Guys, I need some help.
I need to align the image but in the right side of the same line.
This is how it looks now:
[image]

And this is what I need:

[image]

Here's the CSS code I'm using:

```
.term-150 .page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title:after {
content: "";

position: absolute;
display: inline-block;

background:  url(https://www.url.com/logo_.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
width: 95px;
height: 27px;

margin-left: 10px;
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
    </header><!--END MAIN HEADER-->
    
                        <div class="main-page-wrapper">

                                    <div class="page-title page-title-default title-size-default title-design-default color-scheme-light with-back-btn title-shop" style="">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="nav-shop">

                        <div class="shop-title-wrapper">
                                                                                <a href="javascript:woodmartThemeModule.backHistory()" class="woodmart-back-btn"><span>Back to products</span></a>
                                    
                                                                    <h1 class="entry-title">Marvel</h1>
                                                            </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.term-150 .page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title {
    width: 100%;
}
.term-150 .page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background:  url(https://www.url.com/logo_.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 95px;
    height: 27px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luca. But with that code the logo goes over the Marvel title (word)

Comment: That's odd, it should work. Perhaps the title is inline-block too? I added a rule for the title, try it now.

Comment: Oh, no my friend. Same thing https://imgur.com/YOexAF9 Thank you :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you share a link with the page?